# Javascript: Any way to shorten local usage of nested objects?

Tags: javascript, object, variables, global

After coding a complex board game with a ton of variables, objects, and arrays, I've been told that global variables are bad, for various reasons.

One solution given was to wrap the entire javascript code in a function, making it all local.  Another way to put all my variables into one object.  I probably should've just gone with the first solution.  But I attempted the second.  As it will also make saving and loading this variable between turns via AJAX calls easier - ie I only have to save and load one object.

So my old globals were this:

```
let player = 'red';
let tattoos = {red: 0, blue: 0, green: 0};
let statusTrack = { 1: [1], 2: [1], 3: [2], 4: [2], 5: [4],};
```

And now it's like this:

```
let game = {
    player: 'red',
    tattoos: {red: 2, blue: 1, green: 1},
    statusTrack: { 1: [1], 2: [1], 3: [2], 4: [2], 5: [4],}
}
```

Which is great.  Except now my actual code is very hard to read.  A line that used to be this:

```
let stIndex = statusTrack[tattoos[player]].indexOf(player)
```

Is now

```
    let stIndex = game['statusTrack'][game['tattoos'][game['player']]].indexOf(game['player']);
```

So my question:  Is there any way, with a library or code snippet, to convert the code I'm typing into the old format, yet still using the new "everything in one object" format for the variables?

Similar to how adding this one line:

```
let $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
```

let's me emulate the `JQuery` / `Sizzle` selector and type `$('div')` instead of `document.getElementById('div')`?

OR should I just go back to the old way and wrap the whole thing in a function to make it all local?

Comment: Note that `game['statusTrack']` can be written as `game.statusTrack`

Comment: Ah yes.  I do know that but for some reason when I first started this project and I was using nested variables, I read that I should stagger it - like game.statusTrack[1] or whatever. But that wouldn't work for some reason.  It would come back null.  So I would try game['statusTrack'][1] and it worked.  So I just defaulted to using that method for everything.

Comment: `let stIndex = game.statusTrack[game.tattoos[game.player]].indexOf(game.player);` is much easier to read though. Use bracket syntax for property access only when the property name is dynamic or an integer.

Comment: Well in all cases `game['statusTrack']` is exactly the same as `game.statusTrack`. There's no magic to it; that's part of the definition of the language.

Comment: "*wrap the whole thing in a function*" - the part where you run the `let stIndex = …` statement already is inside of a function, right? But no, you should not go back to the old style.

Comment: Yes that is already in a function.  But it was suggested to me to wrap ALL of my javascript in a function, making all of the global variables no longer global.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been told that global variables are bad, for various reasons.

While avoiding the use of global variables is good practice, it's also a very good idea to separate the handling of an app's state from the rest of the code.

One way of creating a separate state handler is with a simple class containing a constructor that initializes the state, and getters and setters for the properties.

This provides a simple way to access and modify the state, while hiding the ugly details.

The question's `game` object:

```js
let game = {
    player: 'red',
    tattoos: {red: 2, blue: 1, green: 1},
    statusTrack: { 1: [1], 2: [1], 3: [2], 4: [2], 5: [4],}
}
```

Would look like this as a class:

```js
class GameState {
  constructor (player, tattoos, statusTrack) {
     this._player = player;
     this._tattoos = tattoos;
     this._statusTrack = statusTrack;
  }
  
  set player(p) { this._player = p; }
  
  get player() { return this._player; }
  
  get tattoo() { return this._tattoos[this._player]; }
  
  get stIndex() {
    const {_statusTrack: sTrack, _player: pl, _tattoos: tattoos} = this;
    const tat = tattoos[pl];
    const activeTrack = sTrack[tat];
    return activeTrack.indexOf(pl);
  }
}

const myGame = new GameState(
  'red',
  {red: 1, blue: 1, green: 1},
  { '1': [ 1 ], '2': [ 1 ], '3': [ 2 ], '4': [ 2 ], '5': [ 4 ] }
);
myGame.player = 'blue';

console.log('myGame.player:', myGame.player);
console.log('myGame.tattoo:', myGame.tattoo);
console.log('myGame.stIndex:', myGame.stIndex);
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  I'm sure that is probably a better way, but that's so over my head!  I just finished converting all my variables. I have two objects now. One for local variables that never need to be passed to the server, and the other for those that do.  I changed them all to dots instead of brackets and it's not too tough on the eyes, and the entire game still works!  Maybe for the next game I do I'll try to learn to use a class, but for now I gotta get the back end hooked up and working so I can make this actually playable online.. and I'm brand new to that too!